# て in 恭悦至極に存じたてまつり

Tags: grammar

恭悦至極に存じたてまつり
I read this in manga before.
Does it say Yasushi Takamori festival?

I don't understand て in this sentence.

Answer (score 2):

「存じ + [奉]{たてまつ}り」

The て is part of the word 「[奉]{たてまつ}る」. From [デジタル大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/137716/meaning/m0u/):

> たてまつる【奉る】
>   1⃣［動ラ五（四）］５ （補助動詞）動詞の連用形に付いて謙譲の意を添え、その動作の及ぶ相手を敬う。…申し上げる。…さしあげる。「御神体を移し**たてまつる**」「よろしく願い**たてまつり**ます」

Here it's used as a humble subsidiary verb (謙譲の意の補助動詞). 「存じ(る)」 is the humble language (謙譲語) of 「知る」「思う」. Here it's used as the latter. 
In other words, 「～～に存じたてまつる」 is the humble form of 「～～に思う」.

「[恐悦]{きょうえつ}[至極]{しごく}」 means "extremely and humbly delighted". 「恐悦」= "humbly delighted", 「至極」= "extreme"

Comment: I thought it was ぞんじたってまつり. Thank you. Is it "I am extremely happy to know it"?

Comment: No, it's humbly expressing "I feel extremely happy". (The 存じ is *not* "know" here.)

Answer (score 1):

> 恭悦至極に存じたてまつり（そうろう）

This is an extremely polite expression of gratitude. It sounds like around the Edo era.
The て is part of the verb 奉る{たてまつる}.  Since たてまつり is the conjugated form to connect to another conjugating word, here そうろう must be missing.

> 恭悦{きょうえつ}＋至極{しごく}に＋存{ぞん}じ＋奉{たてまつ}り＋候{そうろう}

恭悦至極に = being at the highest point of delight
存じ（連用形）＜存じる＝存ずる＝ think
奉り（連用形）＜奉る[補助動詞] 謙譲語[The Humble Language]＝申し上げる
候 [補助動詞 helping verb] ＝ございます [adds an extra sense of profoundness]

Comment: Thank you. What is helping verb?

Comment: 補助動詞=helping verbs=auxiliary verbs. They seem to work as modal verbs just like in English.

Comment: ^ 補助動詞(「助けて**くれる** 」「助けて**もらう** 」「走って**いる** 」など)をauxiliary verbと呼ばれるんですね。助動詞(「う・よう」「れる・られる」「せる・させる」など)はいつもなんと呼んでいらっしゃるんですか？

Comment: Labelings differ person to person. I am not a specialist nor a believer of any particular sect..